# Dark slow hip-hop song (by the Game?)

Tags: identify-this-song, rap, hip-hop

I heard a song a long time ago and I think artist is the Game (Jayceon Terrell Taylor). I don't remember any lyrics but in song there was a part an old man mourning that keep repeating throughout the song. And it was a slow song and video was a kind of dark. Anybody can tell me what that song is?. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably *Dreams* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2K0q74jtV8s

It was one of The Game's first big hits, and featured production by Kanye West with a distinctively mournful vocal sample of Jerry Butler (the "old man") from his song *No Money Down.*